# Where is associated data combined in Clean Architecture?

Tags: android, entity, mvp, use-case, clean-architecture

I'm developing a mobile client app with Clean Architecture + MVP that mostly displays data from an API. Say I have two entities, an **event**, and a **location**, and I want to display a list of events in my app. The data structures behind these two entities look like

```
Event
+ id: Int
+ title: String
+ description: String
+ start: LocalDateTime
+ end: LocalDateTime
+ locationId: Int

Location
+ id: Int
+ address: String
```

—and the view-model my presenter pushes to the view looks like

```
EventViewModel
+ title: String // e.g. "Birthday Party"
+ timeRange: String // e.g. "June 11, 7pm – 10pm"
+ address: String // e.g. "123 Fake St."
```

My question is, at what point in Clean Architecture are the event and location combined to have the event data and location data in one structure?

One option would be a use case which fetches the event, then fetches the location for that event, then combines their data into a response structure for the presenter. The presenter then translates that response structure to the view model (e.g. formatting the start/end date-times into a time range string).

Another option would be for the presenter to execute two use cases, one to fetch the event and another to fetch the event's location, then to combine and translate that data into a view model.

Answer (score 0):

In Clean Architecture all logic goes to either entities or use case interactors. Controllers and presenters should only convert data structures.

That being said you should go for your first option.